# Switching Terraform cloud workspaces in GitHub Actions/Terraform CLI

Tags: terraform, github-actions

We're in the middle of working on a small proof of concept project which will deploy infrastructure to Azure using Terraform. Our Terraform source is held in GitHub and we've using Terraform cloud as the backend to store our state, secrets etc.

Within Terraform cloud we've created two workspaces, one for the `staging` environment and one for the `production` environment.

So far we've used the [guide on the Terraform docs](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/github-actions) to develop a GitHub action which triggers on a push to the `main` branch and deploys our infrastructure to the `staging` environment. This all works great and we can see our state held in Terraform cloud.

The next hurdle is to promote our changes into the `production` environment.

Unfortunately we've hit a brick wall trying to figure out how to dynamically change the Terraform cloud workspace within the GitHub action so it's operating on `production` and not `staging`. I've spent most of the day looking into this with little joy.

For reference the Terraform backend is currently configured as follows:

```
terraform {
  backend "remote" {
    organization = "terraform-organisation-name"

    workspaces {
      name = "staging-workspace-name"
    }
  }
}
```

The action itself does an `init` and then and `apply`.

Obviously with the workspace name hardcoded this will only work on `staging`. Ultimately the questions comes down to how to parameterise or dynamically change the Terraform cloud workspace from the command line?

I feel I'm missing something fundamental and any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I have the exact same problem and cannot seem to work it out. I can't beleive no one has an answer for this.

Comment: Hi baynezy, in the end we had to compromise and work through two separate branches because we couldn't get what is outlined above to work properly. We make all of our changes in a branch and then open a PR from that branch into a `Staging` branch which does a `terraform plan` and puts the output into the PR comments, when the PR is merged it does a `terraform apply`. We use the branch name to determine what to set `TERRAFORM_CONFIGURATION` to which then determines which Terraform cloud workspace to use. I'll try and type this up properly and add it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @AndyM. I worked out you have to use tags to label sibling workspaces. Then you can use `TF_WORKSPACE` environment variable to point at the workspace name.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run `terraform workspace select production` in the same way you would do locally.

If, for some reason, you absolutely need to use this config file, then you could just generate it before you run `terraform apply`. For example, run something like `sed -i 's/staging/production/g' backend.tf` to perform the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
  cloud {
    hostname     = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "Your-Org"

    workspaces {
      tags = [
        "my-service",
        "infrastructure",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then you create a workspace for each environment which has **ALL** of the tags you have specified in the `tags` block. You can then use the `TF_WORKSPACE` environment variable to point at the correct workspace.

```
$env:TF_WORKSPACE="staging-workspace-name"
terraform plan
```